# T9 search function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code I try to write based on last week codewars event that I joined which I can't figure it out during the event.

The question is:

> T9 Autocomplete The file contacts.txt has names and phone numbers.
>
> The format is:
>
> column 1 = name
>   column 2 = phone number
>
> Your program should receive a sequence of numbers and return the
>   possible contacts that it could match on a phone keypad.
>
> The letters for T9 autocomplete are:
>
> [[2, "ABC"],  [3, "DEF"],  [4, "GHI"],  [5, "JKL"],  [6, "MNO"],  [7,
>   "PQRS"],  [8, "TUV"],  [9, "WXYZ"]]
>
> For simplicity: - Ignore 1's and 0's for name matching. - Assume that
>   matches always start at the beginning of the name or phone number
>
> Output the autocomplete contacts for the following inputs:
>
> - 728
> - 5203
> - 273
> - 2738

I paste the contact list (contacts.txt) [here](https://pastebin.com/Y4cE31GZ).

My idea:

1. create a dictionary key-value pair between number and characters
2. translate number into a list of characters e.g. 728 --> ['PQRS', 'ABC', 'TUV']
3. loop through the contacts.txt file and check the first characters whether it is valid in the first element of list in #2 above or not. if yes, then add correct point by 1. then, check the second characters in that line whether it exist in list #2 above or not. if yes, then add another correct point by 1. if not, reset the score and go to next line.
4. If the correct point when the loop finish means we found the result based on the search condition. return that line.

```py
t9_dict = {
    2: "ABC", 
    3: "DEF",
    4: "GHI",
    5: "JKL",
    6: "MNO",
    7: "PQRS",
    8: "TUV",
    9: "WXYZ",
    }

def t9_input(number):

    list_text = []

    for i in str(number):
        if int(i) != 0:
            list_text.append(t9_dict[int(i)])

    return list_text


def read_contact(list_text):

    filename = 'contacts.txt'
    count = 0

    f = open(filename, "r")
    for line in f:

        for j in range(len(list_text)):         
            if count < len(list_text):
                if line.upper()[count] in list_text[count]:
                    count += 1
                else:
                    count = 0
                    break

            else:
                count = 0
                break

            if count == len(list_text):
                f.close()

                return(line)

    f.close()
    return "no result"


#print(t9_input(728))
#print(t9_input(5203))

print(read_contact(t9_input(728))) #return Patricia Adkins        741-256-2766
print(read_contact(t9_input(5203))) #return Kadyn Giles            597-981-0606
print(read_contact(t9_input(273))) #return Brennan Rosales        930-238-6553
print(read_contact(t9_input(2738))) #return no result
```

Even though the above functions return the correct answer, however, I want to know what I can improve further.

Comment: An alternative would be to build a regex from the t9_input.  E.g, 728 would become something like "^([PQRS][ABC][TUV].*)".  The file could then be read in as one string a searched using the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *Toward optimization and reorganization*

`t9_dict` turned into a constant `T9_DICT`.

- `t9_input` function 
  The function would better reflect the intention if named as **`number_to_chars_t9`** (or `number_to_t9chars`).
  As the question stated *"Ignore 1's and 0's"* - instead of executing filtering condition on each iteration `0` and `1` can be stripped at once with flexible [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) function: `str(number).translate({48: None, 49: None})`.
  Next, prefer list comprehension over constructing and appending to a list.
  Even further, it's better to return an immutable `tuple` of `T9` charsets to avoid compromising them.
- **`read_contact`** function

  `list_text` argument is better renamed to a meaningful **`t9_charsets`**.
  `filename` is better defined as a keyword argument with default value: **`def read_contact(t9_charsets, filename='contacts.txt'):`**.

  Instead of verbose `open(...)`, `f.close()` calls - use flexible context manager **`with`** to automate handling of a file resource.

  Nested `for` loops with all those noisy conditions with dragging around `count` variable and `break` statements are just redundant.
  All the crucial job can be done by means of builtin [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (generates respective items pairs until exhausting the shortest iterable) and [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) functions.

---

Finally, here's the full optimized implementation:

```
T9_DICT = {
    2: "ABC",
    3: "DEF",
    4: "GHI",
    5: "JKL",
    6: "MNO",
    7: "PQRS",
    8: "TUV",
    9: "WXYZ",
}


def number_to_chars_t9(number):
    return tuple(T9_DICT[int(num)] 
                 for num in str(number).translate({48: None, 49: None}))


def read_contact(t9_charsets, filename='contacts.txt'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            if all(c.upper() in t9_chars 
                   for c, t9_chars in zip(line, t9_charsets)):
                return line.strip()
    return "no result"
```

Tests:

```
print(read_contact(number_to_chars_t9(728)))
print(read_contact(number_to_chars_t9(5203)))
print(read_contact(number_to_chars_t9(273))) 
print(read_contact(number_to_chars_t9(2738)))
```

The output (consecutively):

```
Patricia Adkins        741-256-2766
Kadyn Giles            597-981-0606
Brennan Rosales        930-238-6553
no result
```

Comment: If the keys for `T9_DICT` were characters instead of ints, the `int()` conversion would not be needed in `number_to_chars_t9()`. e.g., `{'2':'ABC', ...}`

Comment: Thanks, RomanPerekhrest for an amazing reply. There are several things I can learn further during holiday. <3